# ¿Alguna forma de evitar que los passwords queden visibles cuando se aplica un volcado de memoria?

Tags: .net

Buen día,

Tengo un aplicativo realizado en .NET con C#, en una revisión que se hizo para ver la vulnerabilidad se encontró que los datos como el password quedan expuestos.

Se ha utilizado SecureString, core.encrypt, clases marshal sin embargo no se ha logrado el objetivo de ocultarlo.

¿Alguna idea? Por favor.

Saludos!

Es un formulario Sencillo donde se pone un text para el usuario y otro para el password, si realizan el volcado de memoria (archivo DMP), aparece la informacion capturada, es ahi donde viene el problema. Revisando el tema recomiendan el secure string este oculta la variable pero el contenido aparece aun.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: algun ejemplo? no de los passwords, pero que probaron, intentaron?? algun [mcve] para hacer pruebas?

Comment: Prueba con Bcrypt 
https://github.com/BcryptNet/bcrypt.net

Comment: Si utilizáis SecureString si es posible que queden visibles (relacionado, [cómo de seguro es SecureString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.security.securestring(v=vs.110).aspx#HowSecure)).Ahí
 se especifica _En lugar de usar SecureString para proteger las contraseñas, la alternativa recomendada es utilizar un identificador opaco a las credenciales que se almacenan fuera del proceso._ .Para poder ayudar mas, deberíamos tenes mas datos sobre la implementación un [mcve] sería de mucha ayuda.